# Why is my integer variable count not incremenating and adding by 1 in for loop

Tags: java, loops, counter

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjquh.png)

Trying to increment the integer variable by count each time the if condition returned true.

it is not working properly the count is showing zero at all times

i am trying to find the program for prime number using loop

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not a screenshot. Also, check out [this article]https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Never post images of code. Post it as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Additionally... This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: `i%num == 0` for the numbers in the range of `[2, num]` will only ever be true once, when `i == num`. I'd also encourage using brackets/braces a little more liberally.

Comment: Thank you so much for the enlightenment as a beginner I am yet to become familiar with the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if condition or statement from `if(i%num == 0)` to `if(num%i == 0)`. It will lead to correct output. In our case input is number 10 it is divisible by number 2 and number 5. Then the program will print 10 is not an prime number.